# Why is the program throwing this error??: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 36

Tags: java

In this assignment you will write a Tweet Tester.
Twitter allows users to send messages of 140 characters or less. Users direct tweets to specific users by using @mentions and label tweets by using #hashtags. Users may also "retweet" tweets from other users.
For this lab you will ask the user to enter a potential tweet. First you will check to see if it is a valid tweet by checking that the length is less than or equal to 140 characters.
If the tweet is too long print out the number of characters over 140.
If the tweet is valid print Length Correct, then count the number of @mentions and #hashtags and determine whether the tweet is a retweet using the following rules:
Every mention will start with the '@' character and have at least one non-space or non-tab character following it.
All hashtags will start with the '#' character and have at least one non-space or non-tab character following it.
The tweet is a retweet if it contains the string "RT:" anywhere in the text of the tweet. Twitter ignores case, so "RT:", "rt:" and any other possible capitalizations are counted as the same set of characters and all indicate a retweet. You do not need to check for any characters following the "RT:" string.
Remember that the escape sequence, '\t', can be used to check for a tab character.
Sample Run 1:
Please enter a tweet:
RT: This is a #long tweet. An extra long #link. So, when @you write your code it should ignore all of the #hashtags and @mentions since it is too long. It should also ignore retweet strings.
Excess Characters: 50
Sample Run 2:
Please enter a tweet:
This #tweet is #short and has several #hashtags. RT: And it is a retweet.
Length Correct
Number of Mentions: 0
Number of Hashtags: 3
The input was a retweet.
Sample Run 2:
Please enter a tweet:
This @tweet is #short and has #hashtags and @mentions #
Length Correct
Number of Mentions: 2
Number of Hashtags: 2
The input was not a retweet.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
      int h = 0;
      int m = 0;
      int count = 0; 
      char letter;
      boolean r = false;
      String tweet;
      System.out.println("Please enter a tweet:");
      tweet = scan.nextLine();
      int length = tweet.length();

      if (length <= 140)
      {
          while (count <= length)
          {
            letter = tweet.charAt(count);

            if (letter == '#' &&
                tweet.charAt(letter+1) != ' ')
            {
                h++;
            }

            if (letter == '@' &&
                tweet.charAt(letter+1) != ' ')
            {
                m++;
            }

            if ((letter == 'r' || letter == 'R') &&
            (tweet.charAt(letter + 1) == 't' || tweet.charAt(letter + 1) == 'T'))
            {
                r = true;
            }

            count ++;

          }

          System.out.println("Length Correct");
          System.out.println("Number of Mentions: " + (m));
          System.out.println("Number of Hashtags: " + (h));
          if (r == true)
          {
            System.out.println("The input was a retweet.");
          }
          else if (r==false)
          {
            System.out.println("The input was not a retweet.");
          }
      }

       if (length > 140)
       {
        System.out.println("Excess Characters: " + (length - 140));
       }


     }
}
```

Comment: firstly, you will exceed your array with `while (count <= length)` so change to `<` secondly `letter + 1` ? maybe `count + 1` but again you  will exceed your array at the end

Comment: This is way to much text and your code sample makes it hard to see the actual problem. Please reduce the input so it's easier to help you.

Comment: Have you looked into the [757 other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=StringIndexOutOfBoundsException) about this exception ?

Answer (score 1):

Below is the cause of issue.

```
while (count <= length) {
```

and below is the fix

```
while (count < length) {
```